# DB won't restore in an Availability group on secondary server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a moved a sharepoint database to my 2014 SQL cluster.  The primary is fine so I changed the primary to a full recovery and made a full backup.  When I went to the Secondary I performed a restore off the backup with a no recovery mode (which is required for the availability group) and it is stuck in restoring. I restored it with recovery and it comes back fine but I can connect the databases in the availability group.  I am at a loss any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you restore a database with "norecovery" it will remain in restoring mode.... this is the expected behaviour

Regards
Giovan

Comment: I am not sure why but the AG did not want to sync with it.  I performed a log transaction restore and tried again and it took it.  Thank you.  I'm not sure why it had to be so difficult.